RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detectionRuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection in rpi-rf code
Thats the code to receive
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import signal
import sys
import time
import logging

from rpi_rf import RFDevice

rfdevice = None

# pylint: disable=unused-argument
def exithandler(signal, frame):
    rfdevice.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    format='%(asctime)-15s - [%(levelname)s] %(module)s: %(message)s', )

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Receives a decimal code via a 433/315MHz GPIO device')
parser.add_argument('-g', dest='gpio', type=int, default=27,
                    help="GPIO pin (Default: 27)")
args = parser.parse_args()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exithandler)
rfdevice = RFDevice(args.gpio)
rfdevice.enable_rx()
timestamp = None
logging.info("Listening for codes on GPIO " + str(args.gpio))
while True:
    if rfdevice.rx_code_timestamp != timestamp:
        timestamp = rfdevice.rx_code_timestamp
        logging.info(str(rfdevice.rx_code) +
                     " [pulselength " + str(rfdevice.rx_pulselength) +
                     ", protocol " + str(rfdevice.rx_proto) + "]")
    time.sleep(0.01)
rfdevice.cleanup()

i run it,
and getting this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ant/rpi-rf_receive.py", line 28, in <module>
    rfdevice.enable_rx()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/rpi_rf/rpi_rf.py", line 189, in enable_rx
    GPIO.add_event_detect(self.gpio, GPIO.BOTH)
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

i deleted rpi-gpio and installed rpi-lgpio but still didnt work
before this happened i had a similar problem saying
no module found rpi_rf
but ive had it installed. please help me!
i now did sudo pip3 uninstall rpi_rf --break-system-packages
and i get this when i run my code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ant/rpi-rf_receive.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rpi_rf import RFDevice
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpi_rf'

i cant understand what happens
btw i run on ssh
new update
i did this sudo pip3 uninstall rpi-gpio --break-system-packages to keep only lgpio and now i have another error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ant/rpi-rf_receive.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rpi_rf import RFDevice
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/rpi_rf/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rpi_rf import RFDevice
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/rpi_rf/rpi_rf.py", line 9, in <module>
    from RPi import GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

am i close?

Why have you installed Bookworm on a PiZeroW2? This is only recommended for Pi4/5. You have obviously not studied the changes in pip use on python 3.11 but this is only for starters - you seem to have done lots of inexplicable things. WHAT are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

@Milliways i installed the rpi os without gui to run on my 02w , i found it ready and thats what i installed. do u suggest me something else? im new to rpi! i bought a 315mhz transmitter and receiver and i try to capture and send rf signals thats all! btw why not have bookworm? i want the latest version... no one ever told me bookworm was not suggested in 0 2w

You should indicate in your question what OS (I deduced from error messages). Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm Lite will run; I have used on my Pi3A+ (even though it is not suggested by the installer). Debian Bookworm is largely a minor upgrade (python3.11 the major change) but Raspberry Pi Ltd. added a number of other significant changes; kms driver & Network Manager but the Desktop is the major change.

You COULD install rpi-lgpio which is "Compatibility shim for lgpio emulating the RPi.GPIO API" BUT why would you want to on a PiZeroW2 which should already have RPi.GPIO installed.
If you WANT to install for some reason apt install python3-rpi-lgpio but it is only necessary if you want to run existing RPi.GPIO code on a Pi5 and would just add another layer.
You don't seem to have any code which would require RPi.GPIO
sudo pip3 uninstall rpi_rf --break-system-packages wouldn't install (or uninstall) ANYTHING.
If you REALLY wanted to remove a system package (WHY?) you would need to use apt.
If you want to use pip with python3.11 you should create a virtual environment and install there. There are a number of posts explaining this.
rpi_rf is very old code - it may not run on python3.
